# Complex associations for Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Stuck on this one, if you could take a look.. :)

What I want is to get all unfinished projects, including all unfinished tasks for a certain user.

This is my setup so far:

```
User (devise)
    has_one :employee

Employee
    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
    has_and_belongs_to_many :unfinished_tasks, :conditions => { :tasks => { :completed_at => nil } }, :class_name => "Task"
    has_many :unfinished_projects, :through => :unfinished_tasks, :source => :project, :uniq => true   ( :include => :unfinished_tasks OR :include => :tasks ? )

Project
    has_many :tasks

Task
    belongs_to :project
    has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
```

In my view (haml) I'd like to have something like this:

```
- for project in current_user.employee.unfinished_projects

    = project.name

    # THESE ARE NOT THE ONLY THE TASKS FOR THE CURRENT_USER
    - for task in project.tasks    ( OR project.unfinished_tasks ? )

        = task.name
```

This setup works for the projects, there are only projects which have unfinished tasks.

But I'm not sure how to include the unfinished tasks with these projects.

Anyone knows the best way for doing this, I'd like to have a single query for all this if that's possible.

**EDIT:**
The tricky part is that the tasks have to be for the current_user.
The projects are loaded perfectly.

But when it loads the tasks:

```
- for task in project.tasks.unfinished
```

It does this:

```
Task Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` IN (12, 7, 13, 15, 14, 10, 16, 17, 9, 2, 3)
Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` = 12 AND `tasks`.`completed_at` IS NULL
Task Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` = 7 AND `tasks`.`completed_at` IS NULL
Task Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`project_id` = 13 AND `tasks`.`completed_at` IS NULL
etc.
```

What it should do is get the tasks of the employee:

```
Employee
  Projects
    Tasks
```

Which should be the tasks that were inner joined in the projects query.

Comment: What you're asking for is not exactly clear. do you mean you'd like  "unfinished_projects" to be a list of projects which have task that are unfinished? Do you mean that you'd like to use "incomplete_tasks" to mean the tasks that belong to that project that are still unfinished (and not see the finished ones)?

Comment: An unfinished project is a project which has many unfinished tasks. I want all unfinished projects with the unfinished tasks from a certain employee. The ideal would be a single query witch includes all these records.

Comment: The big problem is after I get the projects and loop through the tasks of a project, they are not related to that specific employee anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing this all over again I didn't really find what my problem was.
There are a few things changed now: I'm using scopes, includes for eager load are in the scope, and no scope on the project.tasks itself.

The project model:

```
has_many :tasks
scope :assigned_to, lambda { |employee| { :include => { :tasks => :employees }, :conditions => { :tasks => { :employees => { :id => employee.id } } } } }
scope :unfinished, :include => :tasks, :conditions => { :tasks => { :completed_at => nil } }
```

The view:

```
- for project in Project.assigned_to( current_user.employee ).unfinished
  = project.name
  - for task in project.tasks
    = task.name
```

Gives me this nice MySQL-query:

```
SELECT `projects`.`id` AS t0_r0, `projects`.`name` AS t0_r1, `projects`.`description` AS t0_r2, `projects`.`completed_at` AS t0_r3, `projects`.`created_at` AS t0_r4, `projects`.`updated_at` AS t0_r5, `tasks`.`id` AS t1_r0, `tasks`.`name` AS t1_r1, `tasks`.`description` AS t1_r2, `tasks`.`estimated_duration` AS t1_r3, `tasks`.`calculated_duration` AS t1_r4, `tasks`.`status` AS t1_r5, `tasks`.`completed_at` AS t1_r6, `tasks`.`project_id` AS t1_r7, `tasks`.`created_at` AS t1_r8, `tasks`.`updated_at` AS t1_r9, `employees`.`id` AS t2_r0, `employees`.`alias` AS t2_r1, `employees`.`comments` AS t2_r2, `employees`.`user_id` AS t2_r3, `employees`.`created_at` AS t2_r4, `employees`.`updated_at` AS t2_r5 FROM `projects` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tasks` ON `tasks`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `employees_tasks` ON `employees_tasks`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `employees` ON `employees`.`id` = `employees_tasks`.`employee_id` WHERE `employees`.`id` = 3 AND `tasks`.`completed_at` IS NULL
```

Works like a charm!

Special thanks to Taryn.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my question (above) is a true example of what you'd like to see.

you can use named_scopes to cover this.

For instance:

```
Task
   named_scope :unfinished, :conditions => {:unfinished => true}
```

or whatever condition used to show that it's unfinished. Then you can use:

```
 - for task in project.tasks.unfinished
```

The named_scope for "unfinished_projects" is similar but slightly more complex.
It requires some bare SQL - which will depend on the db that you use, but generally requires that you join the tasks on and find the project sht at have one unfinished task. I'm guessing this might come close to what you need:

```
Project
   named_scope :unfinished, 
    :joins => 'inner join tasks on tasks.project_id = projects.id',
    :conditions => ['tasks.unfinished IS TRUE']
```

You would then use it as above:

```
  - for project in current_user.employee.projects.unfinished
```

For one that only finds projects that have unfinished tasks *for a user*, you can add the user as a parameter to the scope eg:

```
Project
   named_scope :unfinished_for_user, lambda {|the_user_id|
    :joins => 'inner join tasks on tasks.project_id = projects.id',
    :conditions => ['tasks.unfinished IS TRUE AND tasks.user_id = ?', the_user_id]
   }
```

Comment: Trying to use scopes now, hopefully it will make it all a bit more clear. Only problem is the Project.unfinished scope. Really don't know how to create it. scope :unfinished, :condition => { :tasks => "`completed_at` IS NOT NULL" }

Comment: I've updated my comment to include a go at making that work... you may need to have a play around with the sql for that. You can test it just by trying the conditions with "Project.all".

Comment: Oke, I'm using Rails3, and created the following scope: `scope :unfinished, :include => :tasks, :conditions => "'tasks.completed_at IS NOT NULL'"`. Problem now is I don't get unique projects.

Comment: I'm really trippin here, conditions should be `{ :tasks => { :completed_at => nil } }` offcourse

Comment: I've updated my question, the scopes made my models a lot more clear, so that's a relief.. But it's still not working as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question is as follows:

The models:

```
Employee:
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
  has_many :projects, :through => :tasks, :uniq => true

Project:
  has_many :tasks
  scope :unfinished, :include => :tasks, :conditions => { :tasks => { :completed_at => nil } }

Task:
  scope :unfinished, :conditions => { :completed_at => nil }
  scope :of_user, lambda { |user| { :include => :employees, :conditions => { :employees => { :id => user.employee.id } } } }
```

The view:

```
- for project in current_user.employee.projects.unfinished

    - for task in project.tasks.unfinished.of_user( current_user )
```

**I find it VERY annoying that Project.unfinished already includes the incomplete tasks.**

**WHY do I need to get these again, gives me a new query for each project! Should be unnecessary right?**

Comment: To remove the extra sql, look into "eager loading".

Comment: I think that's what my problem is.. I want it to eager load, but everything I try messes up the tasks.. If I include the tasks for eager loading, they are not user-specific anymore..

Comment: hmmm... you can include a requirement for the user_id to match the specified tasks in the named_scope. You can even pass it in as a parameter... I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Taryn, thanks for trying to help me on this one, but I can't really solve this puzzle yet.. I'm going to try it  all over again, and I'll let you know how that works out.. Thanks again!